# How to pause/start/stop Kafka Producer / Kafka Template

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

I'm using a spring boot app with kafka integration and I want to implement an endpoint to stop and start kafka from publishing messages.
The message are triggered in a async way by another endpoints.

The beans `KafkaTemplate<String, String>` or `ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory()` does not have any stop and pause actions.

My goal is to be able to simulate connection failures and make sure those message are stored in a fallback mechanisms that I have in place.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `KafkaTemplate` doesn't have those callbacks because it is a *passive* component which can do the stuff only if we call it.

For the simulation of the connection failure, I would suggest you to implement a custom `ProducerFactory` producing a `KafkaProducer` with mocked or overridden `Future<RecordMetadata> send(ProducerRecord<K, V> record, Callback callback);`. There, in that `ProducerFactory` you can implement appropriate lifecylce callbacks and react to the state in the mentioned `send()` implementation.

The `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.MockProducer` may have something for your to reuse or borrow. For example see its `close()` or `fenceProducer()`.